# Thread1 -[Subject addTasksObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000293cb00'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this SwiftUI app with core data model organized this way:

- Object "Subject" has some properties and a relationship one to many Tasks
- Object "Task" has some properties and a relationship one to one Subject

This is the Task class extension

```
extension Task {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Task> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Task>(entityName: "Task")
    }

    @NSManaged public var taskID: UUID
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var descr: String
    @NSManaged public var type: String
    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var priority: Int
    @NSManaged public var isCompleted: Bool
    @NSManaged public var notificationID: UUID
    @NSManaged public var subject: Subject

}
```

This is the Subject class extension:

```
extension Subject {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Subject> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Subject>(entityName: "Subject")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var icon: String
    @NSManaged public var color: UIColor
    @NSManaged public var subjectID: UUID    
    @NSManaged public var tasks: NSSet?
    
    public var taskArray: [Task] {
        let set = tasks as? Set<Task> ?? []
        
        return set.sorted {
            $0.name < $1.name
        }
    }

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for tasks
extension Subject {

    @objc(addTasksObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToTasks(_ value: Task)

    @objc(removeTasksObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromTasks(_ value: Task)

    @objc(addTasks:)
    @NSManaged public func addToTasks(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeTasks:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromTasks(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

And this is the view where I create a new Task object:

```
struct NewTask: View {
    
    // MARK: - Variables
    
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool                // To close the sheet view and go back to home
    @State private var closeAlert: Bool = false // Close alert trigger
    
    @State private var name: String = ""        // Task's name
    @State private var type: TaskType = TaskType.Homework    // Task's type
    @State private var subject = Subject()      // Task's subject
    @State private var description: String = "" // Task's description
    @State private var priority: Int = 1        // Task's priority
    @State private var date: Date = Date()      // Task's date
    
    
    @State private var notificationEnabled: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "notificationsEnabled")
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc        // Managed Object Context for Core Data managing
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Subject.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var subjects: FetchedResults<Subject>
    
    init() {
        self.subject = subjects[0]
    }
    
    // MARK: - View body
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                
                // Name input
                TextField("app.inputTask.name", text: $name)
                
                // Description input
                TextField("app.inputTask.description", text: $description)
                
                // Priority input
                HStack {
                    Stepper("app.inputTask.priority", value: $priority, in: 1...3)
                    Text(String(priority)).padding(.leading, 10)
                }
                
                // Type input
                Picker(selection: $type, label: Text("app.inputTask.type")) {
                    ForEach(TaskType.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text(LocalizedStringKey($0.rawValue))
                    }
                }
                
                // Subject selection
                Picker(selection: $subject, label: Text("app.inputTask.subject")) {
                    ForEach(self.subjects, id: \.subjectID) { subject in
                        Text(subject.name)
                    }
                }
                
                // Date picker for date
                DatePicker(LocalizedStringKey("app.inputTask.date"), selection: $date, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("Materie:")
                    //print(subjects)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Testing")
                })
            }
            
            
            
            
            .alert(isPresented: $closeAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("app.warning"), message: Text("app.warning.discardChanges"), primaryButton: .default(Text("app.buttons.confirm"), action: {
                    self.showSheet.toggle()
                }), secondaryButton: .default(Text("app.buttons.cancel")))
            }
            
            .navigationBarTitle("app.tasks.newTask")
            
            .navigationBarItems(leading: HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    if !self.name.isEmpty || !self.description.isEmpty {
                        self.closeAlert.toggle()
                    } else {
                        self.showSheet.toggle()
                    }
                    
                }) {
                    Text("app.buttons.close").foregroundColor(Color.red).bold()
                }
            }, trailing: HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    
                    // Create and save the object
                    let task = Task(context: self.moc)
                                        
                    task.name = self.name
                    task.descr = self.description
                    task.priority = self.priority
                    task.type = self.type.rawValue
                    task.date = self.date                    
                    task.taskID = UUID()
                    task.notificationID = UUID()
                    
                    // Relationship
                    task.subject = self.subject
                    subject.addToTasks(task)
                    
                    // Schedule the notification for the task
                    if self.notificationEnabled == true {
                        scheduleNotification(title: name, body: description, date: date, notifUUID: task.notificationID)
                    }
                    
                    // Close the new task view
                    self.showSheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("app.buttons.save").bold()
                }
                .disabled(self.name.isEmpty == true)
            })
                        
        }
    }
}
```

All I want to do is to create the task object and link it to the subject through their relationship.
But when I save the new Task object I get the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Subject addTasksObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000293cb00'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".

I'm using Xcode 12 beta but I don't think it's a bug, I think I'm doin something wrong establishing the relationship after the creation of the task object

Comment: Could the problem be that Subject was a poor choice of name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is in `@State private var subject` initialization - you cannot do that, because `Subject()` is invalid - it should be with context, but context is not available yet, as well as it is not updated in `init`, because fetch request is not executed yet in init, so state remains invalid.

Here is a possible approach to solve this (not tested - because code not testable, so you might needed to fix compiler warnings/errors)

Pay attention on `subject` declaration/setup/usage places.

```
struct NewTask: View {

    // MARK: - Variables

    @Binding var showSheet: Bool                // To close the sheet view and go back to home
    @State private var closeAlert: Bool = false // Close alert trigger

    @State private var name: String = ""        // Task's name
    @State private var type: TaskType = TaskType.Homework    // Task's type
    @State private var subject: Subject?      // << cannot create here, because MOC is not available
    @State private var description: String = "" // Task's description
    @State private var priority: Int = 1        // Task's priority
    @State private var date: Date = Date()      // Task's date


    @State private var notificationEnabled: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "notificationsEnabled")

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc        // Managed Object Context for Core Data managing

    @FetchRequest(entity: Subject.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var subjects: FetchedResults<Subject>

    // MARK: - View body

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {

                // Name input
                TextField("app.inputTask.name", text: $name)

                // Description input
                TextField("app.inputTask.description", text: $description)

                // Priority input
                HStack {
                    Stepper("app.inputTask.priority", value: $priority, in: 1...3)
                    Text(String(priority)).padding(.leading, 10)
                }

                // Type input
                Picker(selection: $type, label: Text("app.inputTask.type")) {
                    ForEach(TaskType.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text(LocalizedStringKey($0.rawValue))
                    }
                }

                // Subject selection
                Picker(selection: $subject, label: Text("app.inputTask.subject")) {
                    ForEach(self.subjects, id: \.subjectID) { subject in
                        Text(subject.name)
                    }
                }

                // Date picker for date
                DatePicker(LocalizedStringKey("app.inputTask.date"), selection: $date, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])

                Button(action: {
                    print("Materie:")
                    //print(subjects)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Testing")
                })
            }




            .alert(isPresented: $closeAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("app.warning"), message: Text("app.warning.discardChanges"), primaryButton: .default(Text("app.buttons.confirm"), action: {
                    self.showSheet.toggle()
                }), secondaryButton: .default(Text("app.buttons.cancel")))
            }

            .navigationBarTitle("app.tasks.newTask")

            .navigationBarItems(leading: HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    if !self.name.isEmpty || !self.description.isEmpty {
                        self.closeAlert.toggle()
                    } else {
                        self.showSheet.toggle()
                    }

                }) {
                    Text("app.buttons.close").foregroundColor(Color.red).bold()
                }
            }, trailing: HStack {
                Button(action: {

                    // Create and save the object
                    let task = Task(context: self.moc)

                    task.name = self.name
                    task.descr = self.description
                    task.priority = self.priority
                    task.type = self.type.rawValue
                    task.date = self.date
                    task.taskID = UUID()
                    task.notificationID = UUID()

                    // Relationship
                    if let subject = self.subject {
                        task.subject = self.subject
                        subject.addToTasks(task)
                    }
                    
                    // Schedule the notification for the task
                    if self.notificationEnabled == true {
                        scheduleNotification(title: name, body: description, date: date, notifUUID: task.notificationID)
                    }

                    // Close the new task view
                    self.showSheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("app.buttons.save").bold()
                }
                .disabled(self.name.isEmpty == true)
            })

        }
        .onAppear {
            // MOC is available here and results are available here, so
            // setup default subject here !!!
            self.subject = self.subjects.first ?? Subject(context: moc)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While waiting I tried in another way and It works, I used subject variable as an index and I modified Picker and ForEach to work with it, it works perfectly.
Anyway thanks for the help, I appreciate it